# Android getBindingAdapterPosition returning -1 sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView populated with objects and inside of my RecyclerView adapter I have a function for renaming the name value of the object, when running this method I use `getBindingAdapterPosition()` to get the selected object from the ArrayList of task objects to rename it, however `getBindingAdapterPosition()` is returning `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` (or -1) only on SOME items in the RecyclerView and on others the function is working properly, I do not know why this is happening and I have tried to battle it by using an if check to check if `getBindingAdapterPosition()` is equal to `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` but that check does not solve the issue it only skips the renaming. I also tried by adding `adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)` thinking that maybe it didn't work because the adapter wasn't being notified of the change, but the issue persists. Why is `getBindingAdapterPosition()` returning -1 only on SOME items and how can I solve this? Is there another method I can use or is there something I am doing wrong without noticing?

Here is the `MyViewHolder` in my RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    TextView textView;
    OnItemListener onItemListener;
    ArrayList<Task> list;
    private final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener, ArrayList<Task> list, RecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleView);
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
        this.list = list;
        this.adapter = adapter;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            onLongClick();
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void onLongClick(int position)
    {
        // Handles the long click event on an item in the RecyclerView,
        // opens a Dialog with an EditText with the name of the task to edit the task name.

        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        // Creates the EditText for user input and style the look and behavior of it.
        final EditText input = new EditText(itemView.getContext());
        input.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.getContext(), R.drawable.edit_text_dialog));
        input.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.colorText));
        input.setText(text);
        input.setSingleLine();
        input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
        input.setPadding(28, 28, 28, 28);

        // Create an AlertDialog for the user to edit the task name.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_edit_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.dialog_edit_message)
                .setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_edit_positive_button, (dialogInterface, i) ->
                {
                    // When the positive button is clicked, save the edited task name.
                    String editedText = input.getText().toString();
                    if (!editedText.isEmpty())
                    {
                    saveEditedTaskName(itemView.getContext(), editedText, position);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_edit_negative_button, (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.cancel());
        // Show the AlertDialog.
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        input.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, actionId, keyEvent) ->
        {
            // Set the listener for the send button on the EditText.
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND)
            {
                // When the send button is clicked, save the edited task name and dismiss the dialog.
                String editedText = input.getText().toString();
                if (!editedText.isEmpty())
                {
                    saveEditedTaskName(itemView.getContext(), editedText, position);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    private void saveEditedTaskName(Context mContext, String editedText)
    {
        // Method to save the edited task name.

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SHARED_PREFS, 0);
        String categoryId = sharedPrefs.getString(MainActivity.CATEGORY_ID_CHOICE, "");

        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

        int adapterPosition = getBindingAdapterPosition();
        if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
        {
            // Problem here!
            Task task = list.get(getBindingAdapterPosition());
            String taskId = task.getTaskId();

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseHelper.getDatabaseReference();
            databaseReference.child(categoryId).child(DatabaseNodes.TASKS)
                    .child(taskId).child(DatabaseNodes.TASK_NAME).setValue(editedText);

            if (adapter != null)
            {
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "An error occurred. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Other code
}
```

**EDIT:** I want to add that it seems like the objects where the issue is occurring that the values can't be renamed because the `getBindingAdapterPosition()` is returning -1 seem to always be in the same positions, it seems to always be somewhere around the 7th and 8th positioned items in the RecyclerView (indexes 6 & 7). Don't know if this matters but thought that i'd share it, seems very odd...

**EDIT:** After further testing, it seems like it's not only those two positions making trouble, if I have more items it can occur later aswell if the list is longer, but as stated earlier, somewhere usually around the same positions, indexes, 6,7,8.

Comment: I think the call chain between `onLongClick` and `saveEditedTaskName` is important. Can you include it in the question? Also is everything happening on main thread?

Comment: @SergeiKozelko There, I just added `onLongClick` to the code in the question.

Comment: So `getBindingAdapterPosition` wasn't called directly from `onLongClick`. In this case getting -1 isn't impossible. If you haven't touched activity's [`windowSoftInputMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) then what might be happening is that activity gets resized when keyboard is shown which causes holder to unbind. You can try setting `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustNothing` to test if that's the case, though it might break the positioning of the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by passing `getBindingAdapterPosition()` as an argument in the `onLongClick()` method call and further to the `saveEditedTaskName()` method and using that variable received in the parameter instead. I do not exactly know why it works, but it did, perhaps someone else can contribute with an explanation?

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    TextView textView;
    OnItemListener onItemListener;
    ArrayList<Task> list;
    private final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener, ArrayList<Task> list, RecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleView);
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
        this.list = list;
        this.adapter = adapter;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            onLongClick(getBindingAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        });
    }

    // Other code

    private void saveEditedTaskName(Context mContext, String editedText, int position)
    {
        // Method to save the edited task name.

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SHARED_PREFS, 0);
        String categoryId = sharedPrefs.getString(MainActivity.CATEGORY_ID_CHOICE, "");

        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
        {
            Task task = list.get(position);
            String taskId = task.getTaskId();

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseHelper.getDatabaseReference();
            databaseReference.child(categoryId).child(DatabaseNodes.TASKS)
                    .child(taskId).child(DatabaseNodes.TASK_NAME).setValue(editedText);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Operation failed, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) say

> Note that if you've called `notifyDataSetChanged`, until the next layout pass, the return value of this method will be `NO_POSITION`.

If you want to lazily process your items (where you know the positions don't change), maybe use `getLayoutPosition` instead.

Comment: How come it only returns `NO_POSITION` on some items and on most it works as it should? Will `getLayoutPosition` work as it should and what does it do?

Comment: `getBindingAdapterPosition` will return the guaranteed actual position. When you edited your RecyclerView, i.e., called `notify...Changed`, the adapter loses it's knowledge. It will only know what is going on again, after in had another look over the displayed items to rebuild the adapter. `getLayoutPosition` on the other hand, just assumes the order of items that is the "last known state". If you actually reorder items inbetween, `getLayoutPosition` will return the wrong position and `getBindingAdapterPosition` will return `NO_POSITION`, just to be safe.

Comment: I tried with `getLayoutPosition` and it still returns an index of -1 sometimes.

Comment: Hey I just edited my question with some further information, perhaps it might be relevant.